# React JS need to get data from one page to other

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router, use-state

I am trying to make a test project where I have a product list page and a checkout page now when I click on the products add to cart button it should save the data into a useState array and I should be able to pass the data from the state to the checkout page. I am kinda stuck please help

Comment: Please share some of your **relevant** code so that you can be helped. Not your whole files but maybe the state of your list page would be a good start.
Are you using redux? The tags say so but you don't mention it in the question

Comment: I am really sorry for replying this late but the issue has been solved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Link component from React-Router:

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: `/checkout/${productId}`,
    state: { data:productData }
  }}
/>
```

or you can use history.push() for example:

```
props.history.push({
      pathname: `/checkout/${productId}`,
      state: { data:productData }
    });
```

According to this, you can consume the state like that:

```
const Checkout = (props) => {
    const {state} = props.location

    return <></>
}
```